# How to Automatically Synchronize pyproject.toml Across Multiple GitHub Repositories?

Tags: python, github, configuration, repository, pyproject.toml

I have a pyproject.toml configuration file located in a central GitHub repository (let's call it central-repo). This file is the main configuration for Python projects and includes various settings that are common across multiple Python projects.

I have a number of other repositories for various Python projects (let's call them project-repos) which all need to use this central pyproject.toml file.

I'm looking for a way to synchronize this central pyproject.toml file across all project-repos automatically whenever there's a change in central-repo. The goal is to maintain a single source of truth for the configuration and avoid manually updating the configuration in each project-repo.

I've tried using GitHub Actions to copy the pyproject.toml file from central-repo and place it into each project-repo. While this works, it triggers additional CI runs and doesn't seem like the most efficient way to keep these files synchronized.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this in a more efficient and manageable way, or is there an existing tool or service that could help with this? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/asottile/all-repos might be useful, but I haven't actually used it at all

Comment: Looks like this could be a bit of a complex solution. I'll give it a try if nothing else comes up. Thanks, @AlexWaygood!